# How to change the type of a trust relationship from "external" to "forest"?

Tags: active-directory

I have an external trust in place between two Active Directory domains in two different forests (one of them Windows Server 2008 R2, the other one Windows Server 2003); but I need the trust to be a forest trust, because this is what System Center Data Protection Manager needs in order to backup servers between different domains.

Is there anyway to modify the type of the existing trust without deleting it?

If deleting and re-creating the trust is actually a requirement, will this create any problem in resource access (user/group mappings, ACLs, etc.) once the trust gets established again?
Blocking cross-domain access for a couple of minutes is not a problem, but having to re-configure *anything* would be a big one.

Comment: I won't post this as an answer, simply because you can google the same as I...http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverDS/thread/6410f41b-4dfa-441a-bc9d-ecc4129e1afb/

Comment: I googled. Really. You had better luck than me :-)

Comment: Or, as someone once said, "your Google-fu is stronger"...

Comment: @TheCleaner, I'd like to accept an answer here, but I don't want to post one myself, since *you* actually found it; if you move that comment to an answer, I'm accepting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this TechNet thread: [Convert External Trust to Forest level trust](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverDS/thread/6410f41b-4dfa-441a-bc9d-ecc4129e1afb/)
(Archived [here](https://archive.is/TSaX9).):

> There will be no change in permission the rights will not change.You need to delete the existing external trust and create new forest trust.

No, rights should not be removed, since you have DNS in place. Create a forest trust and remove external trust.

## Links

- [Checklist: Creating a forest trust](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc756852%28WS.10%29.aspx)
- [Creating Forest Trusts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776940%28WS.10%29.aspx)